# log4j change CONSOLE threshold during java execution

Tags: java, log4j

I've in my `log4j.properties` file :

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, CONSOLE, FILEWARN
...
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.threshold=ERROR
...
```

During Java execution, I would like to put it to `WARM`.

I did not found anything like `Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("CONSOLE").`*...setThreshold("WARN")* 
Is it a solution with some method, or have I to reaload some dedicated properties File with 
`log4j.appender.CONSOLE.threshold=WARN` inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setThreshold` method is defined on `AppenderSkeleton` (the abstract base class of all the standard appenders), not on the `Appender` interface directly.

```
((AppenderSkeleton)Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("CONSOLE"))
  .setThreshold(Level.WARN);
```